# C# Have to run code twice to work - Geo locator

Tags: c#, gps

im programming some code which when a button is pressed, it will output your gps co ordinates. For some reason it only works when i click it twice or more. even if i wait a minuite and then click it, i have to click it again for it to work and im not sure why. here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Device.Location;

namespace Location
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetLocation();
    }

    static void GetLocation()
    {
        GeoCoordinateWatcher GEOWatcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();

        GEOWatcher.TryStart(false, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));

        GeoCoordinate Coordinates = GEOWatcher.Position.Location;

        if (Coordinates.IsUnknown != true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Latitude: " + Coordinates.Latitude + ", Longitude: " + Coordinates.Longitude);
            Console.WriteLine("https://www.google.co.uk/#q=" + Coordinates.Latitude + "," + Coordinates.Longitude);

            GEOWatcher.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Location currently unavaliable");
        }
    }
}
}
```

any help is appriciated, also if you have any tips or improvments on my code please comment them, thanks

Comment: Have you tried increasing the time out value?

Comment: yes that doesnt do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you indicate it "does not work" what are you actually saying?

Are you saying that you get the message "Location currently unavailable"? If so, this is probably because it takes some time for the GPS unit in the device to get locks on the satellites.

Edit below to explain my comment below:

The GeoCoordinateWatcher will need some time to lock onto the satellites and provide a consistent result. Moving the GeoCoordinateWatcher into the class itself (so it doesn't get garbage collected when the button click event ends) will provide some relief, but it still wont be able to give you a result as soon as you start the app. Something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    GeoCoordinateWatcher GEOWatcher;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // this will start the GeoCoordinateWatcher when the app starts
        GEOWatcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
        GEOWatcher.TryStart(false, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetLocation();
    }

    static void GetLocation()
    {
        GeoCoordinate Coordinates = GEOWatcher.Position.Location;

        if (Coordinates.IsUnknown != true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Latitude: " + Coordinates.Latitude + ", Longitude: " + Coordinates.Longitude);
            Console.WriteLine("https://www.google.co.uk/#q=" + Coordinates.Latitude + "," + Coordinates.Longitude);

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Location currently unavaliable");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeh thats what i meant. but even so i can give it a minuite or 2 and press it once and it still says unavaliable till i click it again

Comment: @Will as you have the GeoCoordinateWatcher in the same scope as the button, the GeoCoordinateWatcher will need to start from scratch again every time you click the button. Try moving the GeoCoordinateWatcher into the class itself.

Comment: oh thats fixed it, i moved the geowatcher outside the button and it works everytime now, thanks